# Qt: How to determine whether a widget is visible or not in the QScrollArea?

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea

Someone suggested that I re-implement the `QWheelEvent` handler and check each child widgets' `visibleRegion` is 0 or not.

Are there any better suggestions?

Comment: Nyaruko, I am looking for the same, if you get any solution please add.

Answer (score 3):

When you add the widget. Give it a name.

```
QWidget* myWidget = new QWidget;
myWidget->setObjectName( "myWidget" );
...
//create scroll area
//add a layout to the scroll area
...
scrollArea->layout()->addWidget( myWidget );
```

Then, check visibility like so:

```
QWidget* widget = scrollArea->findChild< QWidget* >( "myWidget" );
std::cout << widget->isVisible() << std::endl;
```

You could keep a list of your widget names to more easily loop through and check when you're ready.